# Bootstrap switch error - undefined is not an object (evaluating 'a[o].apply')

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, checkbox, switch-statement

I am not able to switch state of bootstrap switch. Could not understand why the error is being thrown. I use safari

```
<div class="form-group input-group pull-left" style="margin-top:0.25em;margin-left:-0.70em">
  <input type="checkbox" id="cb_project_status"  name="cb_project_status" class="switch" data-size="mini" data-on-color="success" data-off-text="Inactive" data-on-text="Active" data-off-color="warning">                                      
</div>
```

Using JQuery I am trying to dynamically set the status

```
if(dataset["PROJECT_STATUS"]=="ACTIVE"){
  $('#cb_project_status').bootstrapSwitch('setState', true, true);
}else{
  $('#cb_project_status').bootstrapSwitch('setState', false, true);
}
```

I am getting the above error thrown from line 13533 of bootstrap-switch.min.js
Any idea why this is happening?